# Combining parsers in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, applicative

I'm given the following parsers

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }

instance Functor Parser where
   fmap f p = Parser $ \s -> (\(a,c) -> (f a, c)) <$> parse p s

instance Applicative Parser where
   pure a = Parser $ \s -> Just (a,s)
   f <*> a = Parser $ \s ->
     case parse f s of
       Just (g,s') -> parse (fmap g a) s'
       Nothing -> Nothing

instance Alternative Parser where
   empty = Parser $ \s -> Nothing
   l <|> r = Parser $ \s -> parse l s <|> parse r s

 ensure :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a
 ensure p parser = Parser $ \s ->
    case parse parser s of
      Nothing -> Nothing
      Just (a,s') -> if p a then Just (a,s') else Nothing

 lookahead :: Parser (Maybe Char)
 lookahead = Parser f
   where f [] = Just (Nothing,[])
         f (c:s) = Just (Just c,c:s)

 satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
 satisfy p = Parser f
   where f [] = Nothing
         f (x:xs) = if p x then Just (x,xs) else Nothing

 eof :: Parser ()
 eof = Parser $ \s -> if null s then Just ((),[]) else Nothing

 eof' :: Parser ()
 eof' = ???
```

I need to write a new parser `eof'` that does exactly what `eof` does but is built only using the given parsers and the
 Functor/Applicative/Alternative instances above. I'm stuck on this as I don't have experience in combining parsers. Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand it easier, we can write it in an equational pseudocode, while we substitute and simplify the definitions, using Monad Comprehensions for clarity and succinctness.

Monad Comprehensions are just like List Comprehensions, only working for any `MonadPlus` type, not just `[]`; while corresponding closely to `do` notation, e.g. `[ (f a, s') | (a, s') <- parse p s ]  ===  do { (a, s') <- parse p s ; return (f a, s') }`.

This gets us:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> Maybe (a,String) }

instance Functor Parser where
   parse (fmap f p)  s  =  [ (f a, s') | (a, s') <- parse p s ]

instance Applicative Parser where
   parse (pure a)    s  =  pure (a, s)
   parse (pf <*> pa) s  =  [ (g a, s'') | (g, s')  <- parse pf s 
                                        , (a, s'') <- parse pa s' ]

instance Alternative Parser where
   parse empty s      =  empty
   parse (l <|> r) s  =  parse l s <|> parse r s

ensure :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a -> Parser a
parse (ensure pred p) s  =  [ (a, s') | (a, s') <- parse p s, pred a ]

lookahead :: Parser (Maybe Char)
parse lookahead []       =  pure (Nothing, [])
parse lookahead s@(c:_)  =  pure (Just c,  s )

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
parse (satisfy p) []      =  mzero
parse (satisfy p) (x:xs)  =  [ (x, xs) | p x ]

eof :: Parser ()
parse eof s  =  [ ((), []) | null s ]  

eof' :: Parser ()
eof'  =  ???
```

By the way thanks to the use of Monad Comprehensions and the more abstract `pure`, `empty` and `mzero` instead of their concrete representations in terms of the `Maybe` type, this same (pseudo-)code will work with a different type, like `[]` in place of `Maybe`, viz. `newtype Parser a = Parser { parse :: String -> [(a,String)] }`.

So we have

```
ensure    :: (a -> Bool) -> Parser a           -> Parser a
lookahead ::                Parser (Maybe Char)
```

<sub>*(`satisfy` is no good for us here .... why?)*</sub>

Using that, we can have

```
ensure  .......  ......                        :: Parser (Maybe Char)
```

<sub>*(... what does `ensure id (pure False)` do? ...)*</sub>

but we'll have a useless `Nothing` result in case the input string was in fact empty, whereas the `eof` parser given to use produces the `()` as its result in such case (and otherwise it produces nothing).

No fear, we also have

```
fmap :: (  a      ->   b )                     -> Parser a        ->  Parser b
```

which can transform the `Nothing` into `()` for us. We'll need a function that will always do this for us,

```
alwaysUnit nothing  =  ()
```

which we can use now to arrive at the solution:

```
eof'  =  fmap ..... (..... ..... ......)
```

Comment: Thanks you! I'm stuck on this hint :
ensure  .......  ......                        :: Parser (Maybe Char)  
trying  
ensure <some_function>  lookahead   

but not sure what <some_function>  it needs to map from  (Maybe Char)  to Boolean

Comment: I ended up starting with: 
 ensure (\s -> s==Nothing )  lookahead  
does it make sense ?

Comment: Based on all this I think my solution will be 

eof'= fmap (\x -> ())   (  ensure (\s -> s==Nothing ) lookahead)

Comment: Later in the HW is see this 
ws = pure () <* many (satisfy isSpace)

Will it be possible to get explanation how to read it ? I know that it is removing leading spaces but not sure how

Comment: `ensure (\s -> s==Nothing )` yes. or, with pattern matching instead of the `==` (which is the same here, with `Char`, but in general is better because does not impose the `Eq` constraint in `Eq a => Maybe a` needlessly) `(\s -> case s of Nothing -> True ; _ -> False)`). besides, you could try you solution and see whether it works. :)

Comment: you're welcome, and kudos for trying it out yourself and arriving at a solution. next times you will be bolder, and will go farther on your own, no doubt. :)